# How to show errors in the Traefik Dashboard?

Tags: traefik

My Traefik (v2.10 and v3.0) Dashboard never shows any errors, even when I intentinally make some, the router will either disappear from the success tab (e.g. for route definition error) or just act as nothing is wrong (e.g. for tls error). The errors do show up in the logs.

Any idea why? What config should I use to let the errors show? Or if my config is correct, could you give me an example of an error that should show up in the Dashboard?

My config:

```
log:
  level: ERROR

api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true
  debug: true

providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
    network: admin_traefik
  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/traefik-ssl.yml

entrypoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entrypoint:
          to: https
          permanent: true
  https:
    address: ":443"
    http:
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt

certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      email: XXX
      storage: /acme/acme.json
      httpchallenge:
        entrypoint: http
```

Errors are present in the logs:

```
traefik     | 2023-10-02T10:44:48Z ERR Router uses a non-existent certificate resolver certificateResolver=letsencrypt2 routerName=https-XXX@docker
```